# returning scope.$watch value to a link function of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a custom directive which attempts to append some HTML to its element via a link function.

I am able to append the string of the `tmpl` variable to the element just fine, but I am `scope.$watch`ing the `scope.value` which is defined by an `ng-model` input from a user, and it's not appending.

To be clear, I would like to have the `ng-model`ed value to be appended to the directive via the `scope.$watch` in the link function—however, `return tmpl += oldValue;` does not seem to be appending itself to the `tmpl` variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <input ng-model="scoped.value">
    {{scoped.value}}
    <br><br>
    <artboard></artboard>
  </body>

</html>
```

And the app:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.directive("artboard", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            var tmpl = "Please append newValue here:";

            scope.$watch("scoped.value", function(newValue){
                return tmpl += newValue;
            });

            tmpl += "\<br\>\<br\>\<br\>" + "End appendage";

            element.append(tmpl);
        }
    };
});
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/SV5jxsc7DhB9hH9Pob7r?p=preview

**EDIT**: I have updated the Plnkr which shows what I am trying to do a little bit better:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SV5jxsc7DhB9hH9Pob7r?p=preview

why is 'hi' undefined?

Comment: why don't you just use `template:'Please ...{{scoped.value}} <br><br>End..."`? Not 100% clear what behavior you are looking for

Comment: I would like to do that, but I am trying to do this to set some css properties, and expressions don't work within style tags. Thanks though ^_^. It would also be nice to know just **why** this won't work.

Comment: @nikkwong you aware of ng-style and ng-class?

Comment: @shaunhusain, yes—but that can only be used to attach styles to an attribute of an element—I would like to use this to maybe create an entire style sheet, or something :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your `scope.$watch` does change the `tmpl` but doesn't do anything with it.

If you reorganized your code to look like this, it would do the same thing it does now:

```
        var tmpl = "Please append newValue here:";
        tmpl += "\<br\>\<br\>\<br\>" + "End appendage";
        element.append(tmpl);

        scope.$watch("scoped.value", function(newValue){
            return tmpl += newValue;
        });
```

The line of code that appended the element with `tmpl` is only ever called when the directive is linked.

Even if you do have your `$watch` function do something with tmpl, watching the `scope.value` will fire the callback anytime there is a change to value. So typing `hello`, will make your `tmpl` have `h`, `he`, `hel`, `hell`, and `hello` appended to it.

Comment: Awesome. Totally understand. Thanks for that. Now what's the way to achieve what I am attempting to do? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you're looking for?

http://plnkr.co/edit/rORuEK7kL8v3Feya8up2?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])

.directive("artboard", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            var tmpl = "Please append oldValue here:";
            var end = "\<br\>\<br\>\<br\>" + "End appendage";

            scope.$watch("scoped.value", function(newValue, oldValue){
              while(element[0].firstChild){
                element[0].removeChild(element[0].firstChild)
              }
              element.append(tmpl+newValue+end)
            });


            element.append(tmpl+end);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i think the oldvalue newvalue wording was a bit confusing. I updated it to just reflect the newvalue, which is what i want appended to the tmpl variable. thanks :-)